# Magento redirect after issue _prepareDownloadResponse

Tags: magento

```
>       return $this->_prepareDownloadResponse(
>           'invoice'.Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->date('Y-m-d_H-i-s').'.pdf',
> $pdf->render(),           'application/pdf'
```

Is it still possible to force page redirect or refresh after _prepareDownloadResponse?

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work or not; remove return and add this line underneath $this->_prepareDownloadResponse .......... return $this->_redirect('*/*/');

Comment: I tried this before I think. The problem lies in the end of connection and response code for a download (already) generated by  _prepareDownloadResponse

Comment: Confirm. Not working, any other good ideas???

Comment: try to redirect or refresh the page using javascript on click event or whatever event want to apply it on. Fire 2 methods: one for download action followed by redirect action.

Comment: I will try something this weekend. Problem is that it actually triggers a whole massaction and the download is the last step. But this definately is a good step to start with. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't seem possible currently.